# Does CentOS 7 stop services upon shutdown?

Tags: mysql, services, nginx

I have installed several services such as MySQL database and nginx on a CentOS 7 machine.

I would like to know if CentOS automatically stops all of the installed services upon receiving a shutdown or power off command.  It is, for well-known reasons, important that a service such as MySQL (or indeed PostgreSQL, or MariaDB, or Percona, or many other database systems) shut down *cleanly*, and not simply be killed without the server having the chance to flush its database tables, indexes, and whatnot from memory to disc.

If this is not automatic, is it possible for me to write a hook script to inform the OS to terminate these processes cleanly before shutting down?

Comment: There isn't really a way to power off the computer without stopping these processes. Whether they are shut down _cleanly_ likely depends on your init system and how you choose to shut down the machine

Comment: @Fox does it works like Windows where all services are stopped before shutting down?

Comment: In general, yes. Unless you force an immediate shut down, or install scripts that lack stop actions for the init system, things will terminate cleanly. If you installed via some kind of package manager, you are almost certainly safe

Comment: Which version of Linux are you using, did you install these from packages supplied by your distro? If the answer is yes, it's fairly safe to assume they are shutting down cleanly - I haven't seen a single distro that doesn't provide means to shut daemons down properly; even if it didn't the init system (be it SysV, upstart, systemd, .. ) will typically send a SIGTERM to processes and wait for a bit before killing them ...

Comment: From the questioner's other questions, I suspect that this is more what the questioner should have asked.